How can I find a solution to this matrix equation?
$$D=X-M(X\circ P)$$
Solve for $X$
where
$D, X, P$ are vectors of size $n$.
$M$ is a matrix of size $n \times n$.
$X\circ P$ indicates element wise multiplication of $X$ and $P$ such that $(X \circ P)_i = X_i P_i$
I am aware that in general, some values of $M$ would support multiple solutions of $X$. But I suspect that in my cases there are unique solutions, so a strategy that finds any solution in the general case would suffice. Even some iterative algorithm would be acceptable.
For extra credit, is it possible to determine, based on $M$, when a unique solution exists?

If you consider the data of $P$ as "inside your matrix" $M$, you can go back to the standard theory of linear systems. Explicitly, $X\circ P$ is equal to the matrix multiplication $diag(P) X$, where $diag(P)$ is simply the diagonal matrix with entries the coefficients of $P$, so you're asking how to solve $D= (I_n - M diag(P))X$.

@AntonioLorenzin this is an awesome trick to know. I should be able to take it from here.

Rewrite your equation as $D= X - M \mathcal{D}_P X$ where $\mathcal{D}_P = \begin{pmatrix} p_1 & 0 & \ldots \\  0  & p_2 & \ldots \\ \ldots & 0  & p_n  \end{pmatrix}$
So the problem becomes a standard system of equations $D=(I-M\mathcal{D}_P)X$.
If $I-M\mathcal{D}_P$ is invertible, you find $X= (I-M\mathcal{D}_P)^{-1}D$. In this case (1 is not an eigenvalue of $M\mathcal{D}_P$) you have unique solution of the problem.
Otherwise, use standard linear algebra theorems to find solutions (if any, they will be infinite).
